# Drive Write Protected on ALL Machines in Domain

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, write-protect

I have a domain of about 25 computers. I have a External 1TB hard drive with a write protection lock on it I use to put Windows updates on the system. In July I plugged the drive into my WSUS server (Server 2008 R2) with the lock on so I don't write over the WSUS info on the drive and copied the info to the DC without a problem. All updates went onto the WSUS server and were pushed out to the system without a problem.

Today I got another batch for August to put onto my WSUS server and when I go to plug in the USB it gives me an error saying

```
Drive is not accessible
The media is write protected.
```

I know it is write protected. It was write protected last month when I used it but still allowed me onto the disk to copy files from it.

I took the drive off the WSUS server and plugged it into 3 of the Windows 7 Pro (x64) machines on the same domain. They ALL say the same thing.

So I plugged it into a different domain I have with Windows 10 Pro (x64) and Windows Server 2016 and it will let me into the drive without a problem.

I have tried uninstalling all the updates from July on one of my Windows 7 machines and plug it back in but with no change.

Its across the entire domain. Anyone have any idea what is blocking my drive being read? It reads on EVERY OTHER system but this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went back to a Windows 10 computer and copied the contents to that computer then reformatted the drive again as NTFS. Placed contents back onto the drive and now it works again on Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 machines. Not sure what happened between the 2 OSs but it is working now.